# Slick toolbar example a la RubySource's implementation?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Whilst [poking around on RubySource](http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/) recently, I saw that they'd implemented an elegant little toolbar that appears when you scroll down your page:

[image]

Quick screencast: http://screencast.com/t/VnqE2BnzR6M1

As far as I can tell this is a custom implementation on top of their WordPress theme.  Is there something similar that is already wrapped up in a package or an example demonstrating an implementation of such a toolbar?

(I'm particularly interested in a Rails solution, but this seems rather handily adaptable given any initial prerolled solution.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/11/sticky-menus-are-quicker-to-navigate/

In the end of it there are several implementations of a similar behavior, which is achieved using js/css since it's done in the client.

Comment: If you don't want to use js plugins, the logic behind the behavior is that you keep the menu hidden till you detect that the user have scrolled the page a certain amount, then you show the menu.